# Triggering an html file upload text field?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've stumbled across some code that works in Firefox but not Chrome.

What seems to be happening is that there is a file upload textfield that
is sized in CSS.  There is also an Upload button immediately to its right for
the user to click to open a dialog to select a file.  The textfield
length is 60, which I think is used to overlay the "Upload" button and not size the field.
I've reduced 60 to 50 in Firebug and it stops working.

How can I invoke the file upload dialog from the Upload button?  I
think I need to send some sort of click event to the textfield.

```
File: __________________ Upload   | Clicking field or Button opens file dialog
```

I've extracted the HTML:

```
<input name="fileField" id="fileField" type="file" size="60">
<span><input type="text" id="fileUploadField"><span></span></span>
<a href="javascript://" class="button" id="uploadButton"><span class="action">Upload</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
document.getElementById('uploadButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('fileField').click();

    return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: Just noticed that this doesn't work in IE.  Should I use jQuery?

Comment: yes, you're right - should've mentioned that i wrote a standards based implementation. using jQuery to abstract away browser incompatibilities is a great idea ;)